# Adding array elements with a for(reach) loop

Tags: php, arrays, json, for-loop, dynamic

(First a bit/lot of context at the bottom is the question)

I am writing an API that returns a planning amongst other things. The response is in JSON and should be as followed:

```
"Planning":
  [
  {
    "Name": "Overview",
    "Dates":
      [
      {
        "Date": "yyyy-mm-dd",
        "Division1": "type",
        "Division2": "type"
      },
      {
        "Date": "yyyy-mm-dd",
        "Division1": "type",
        "Division2": "type"
      },
      ...
      ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "Division1",
    "Dates":
      [
      {
        "Date": "yyyy-mm-dd",
        "Type": "type",
        "Description": "type"
      },
      ...
      ]
  },
  ...
```

There is the standard blok `"Name": "Overview"` this is always returned, and for each division the requester is a part of, a block with `"Name":"Divisionname"` is added to the response.

The issue I have is that the amount or names of the divisions aren't set in stone. There can be more or less depending on the deployment.
To cover for this I wrote the following code:

```
<?php
    ...
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `idDivision` FROM Division;");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($idDivision);
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        $Divisions[] = $idDivision;
        $$idDivision = array();
    }
    ...
?>
```

This should create an array for each division with the array name being the id of that division (correct?).

Then I get the planning data from the DB which i store in the multiple arrays that I will later use for the response building:

```
<?php
$stmt->bind_result($type, $date, $idDivision, $day, $description, $note);
while($stmt->fetch()){
    if(checkarray($date, $arr_date) != true){
        array_push($arr_date, $date);
        array_push($arr_day, $day);
    }
    array_push($$idDivision, $type); //This should push it into the correct array.
}
?>
```

At the end I want to combine all this into the respons ofcourse (This is where I am lost):

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i <= count($arr_date); $i++){
    $planning[0]['Dates'][] = array(
        "Date" => $arr_date[$i],
            // How to add every division with "arrayname" => "$type" here?
        );
}
?>
```

As in the comment above, i don't know how to add a `key:value` for each division that i found dynamically so that it becomes:

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i <= count($arr_date); $i++){
    $planning[0]['Dates'][] = array(
        "Date" => $arr_date[$i],
        "Division1" => $value,
        "Division2" => $value,
        "Division3" => $value,            
        // and so on for every division
        );
}
?>
```

Is there a way to do this or should I even go about doing this a different way? I feel like I should/could use the `$Divisions` array.

Comment: Can you make it more clear please ?

Comment: @KubiRoazhon clearified what the end result should be.

Comment: Division is an array that contains the ids?

Comment: `$Divisions` is an array with all the id's yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this.

```
for($i = 0; $i <= count($arr_date); $i++){
    $planning[0]['Dates'][$i]["Date"] = $arr_date[$i];

     for($j=0;$j<count($division);$j++){
       $planning[0]['Dates'][$i]["division$j"] = $division[$j];
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Oh ofcourse. Thank you. Now i just have to figure out how to get the correct values!